# .bashrc cannot be sourced, how can I debug?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging

When .bashrc is sourced, my terminal immediately closed - I pinpointed it to ~/.bashrc - what's the best way to debug this? Should echo every line to another file? Is there a log I can look to?

It looks like this line is causing the terminal window to close:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/xyz/oresoftware
```

that file path doesn't exist, so I change it to something that exists:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/oresoftware
```

but would `ssh-add` close my terminal window?

Comment: Paste the file.

Comment: looks like it was running ssh-add against a file that didn't exist, but I don't know why that would cause the terminal window to close. I will add the line.

Comment: I assume that you can get to a shell by renaming `.bashrc`. (1) What does `type ssh-add` report? (2) Let’s assume that the suspicious `ssh-add` command is on line 42 of your `.bashrc`.  Copy lines 1-41 of `.bashrc` to `.bashrc41` and `source` that.  Does your terminal close?  If it does, the problem occurs before the `ssh-add`. (3) Otherwise, do `type ssh-add` again. (4) Then type `ssh-add ~/.ssh/xyz/oresoftware`.  Now does your terminal close? Then the `ssh-add` is causing it. (5) If step 4 didn’t kill your terminal, copy lines 1-42 of `.bashrc` to `.bashrc42` and `source` that. What happens?

Comment: @AlexanderMills What operating system are you using? What terminal application are you using?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, several different terminals / psuedo-ttys were experiencing the same problem...the native terminal for Ubuntu, as well as the JetBrains terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found an answer to this question here:
[Any command in my terminal that exits with non-zero code closes my terminal window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407385/any-command-in-my-terminal-that-exits-with-non-zero-code-closes-my-terminal-wind)

What was happening is that `set -e;` was set before the `ssh-add` call, and `ssh-add` was exiting with non-zero code, which then caused my terminal window to close.

So ultimately it was a `set -e;` issue, so thanks @StephenKitt for pointing that out because that helped me. `set -e;` was in a file which .bashrc was `source`'ing.